# Values() constructor in SQL Server 2008 and triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two tables `Employee` and `Emp_Audit`.

On table `Employee`, I have an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, which fires when I insert rows into `Employee`. The function of trigger is to insert the rows into the `Emp_Audit` table that have been inserted into `Employee`.

The trigger works fine when I explicitly use 'insert values' for each record to be inserted in `Employee` as

```
 INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('Anees',1000);
 INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('Rick',1200);
 INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('John',1100);
 INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('Stephen',1300);
 INSERT INTO Employee_Test VALUES ('Maria',1400);
```

Trigger inserts all these rows inti  `Emp_Audit` -------------GOOD

But when I use values constructor as

```
insert into dbo.Employee_Test
values   ('Kritika', 25000),
         ('Ritu', 15000),
         ('Maduri', 7000),
         ('Dinkar', 7000);
```

Only the first row `('Kritika', 25000)` gets inserted into `Emp_Audit`

The whole query is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_Test
(
Emp_ID INT Identity,
Emp_name Varchar(100),
Emp_Sal Decimal (10,2)
)

CREATE TABLE Employee_Test_Audit
(
     Emp_ID int,
     Emp_name varchar(100), 
     Emp_Sal decimal (10,2), 
     Audit_Action varchar(100), 
     Audit_Timestamp datetime 
) 

-----------------------Trigger------------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsertAfter ON [dbo].[Employee_Test]
FOR INSERT 
AS
   declare @empid int; 
   declare @empname varchar(100); 
   declare @empsal decimal(10,2); 
   declare @audit_action nvarchar(200); 

   select @empid = inserted.Emp_ID   
   FROM inserted;  
   select @empname = inserted.Emp_name 
   from inserted;  
   select @empsal = inserted.Emp_Sal  
   from inserted;  

   set @audit_action = 'Record Inserted after Insert Trigger Fired';  

   INSERT INTO Employee_Test_Audit 
   VALUES(@empid, @empname, @empsal, @audit_action, GETDATE());  
   GO

   print('Insert trigger FIRED') 

   insert into dbo.Employee_Test  
   values ('Kritika', 25000), 
          ('Ritu', 15000), 
          ('Maduri', 7000), 
          ('Dinkar', 7000);
```

Comment: You haven't *shown* the trigger, the piece of code that is undoubtedly broken here - it probably assumes that `inserted` contains a single row, which is a poor assumption, as you're seeing. We can't help you fix it though if you don't show the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, what you want is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsertAfter ON [dbo].[Employee_Test]

FOR INSERT

AS

INSERT INTO Employee_Test_Audit (Emp_ID, Emp_name, Emp_Sal, Audit_Action, Audit_Timestamp)

SELECT Emp_ID,Emp_name,Emp_Sal,
    'Record Inserted after Insert Trigger Fired',GETDATE()
from inserted;
```

Because [`inserted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191300.aspx) can contain *multiple* rows (or no rows), you have to treat it as a table. I've never seen any different behaviour, but there's no guarantee (in your version) that all of the variables would have been assigned values from the *same* row even.

Also, you really should get into the habit of supplying a column list to the [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgInsertAfter 
    ON [dbo].[Employee_Test]
    FOR INSERT
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.Employee_Test_Audit(Emp_ID, Emp_name, Emp_Sal, ..., ...)
    SELECT 
          i.Emp_ID
        , i.Emp_name
        , i.Emp_Sal 
        , 'Record Inserted after Insert Trigger Fired'
        , GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED i

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of why only one record inserted is when you assign value to the variable using select then it don't provide any error and set the value to any arbitrary value in the column.
and also using that method only insert one record. So correct trigger code should be

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsertAfter ON [dbo].[Employee_Test]

FOR INSERT

AS

INSERT INTO Employee_Test_Audit

SELECT Emp_ID,Emp_name,Emp_Sal,
    'Record Inserted after Insert Trigger Fired',GETDATE()
from inserted;
```